# Requesting non-default number of items in RSS document

Tags: rss, url-parameters, syndication

Is there a standard way to request other/more than a default number of (say, typically 10) items to be included in a [RSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) document as returned from a web feed/server. For instance do some/most [web feeds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_feed) understand a URL parameter to this effect and what would the syntax be?

I am thinking of a general scheme with URLs of the type:

> http://some.web.feed?count=20

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard way because it's dependent on how a site publishes its feeds.

Some may allow you to set a parameter to ask for a certain count of items. Others may not. This is up to the individual sites to implement or accept.

You will have to read any available documentation or tips per source on if they allow for such customisation.